# Disabling touchscreen when display is closed

Tags: windows-8, touchscreen

I'm wanting to know how to disable the touch screen when the lid is closed. I have recently purchased a windows 8 computer with a touchscreen. The problem is that when the display is closed, the touch screen recognizes input from the keyboard or something and begins typing a password in, I can hear it typing when the sound is on and it is very annoying. I can't find a  simple solution to this through my google searches. So I was curious as to if anyone knew a script, or how to write one, for disabling the touchscreen when the lid's closed. I have not been able to find a setting anywhere for doing so, or even disabling the touch screen. I could just have it go to sleep every time the lid is closed like the factory defaults, but that doesn't help when I'm downloading a large file and would like to keep my screen off and closed while I am gone. The laptop in question is, if it matters, this one: http://www.bestbuy.com/site/Asus+-+Ultrabook+13.3%22+Touch-Screen+Laptop+-+4GB+Memory+-+128GB+Solid+State+Drive+-+Radiant+Black/6906246.p?id=1218812711231&skuId=6906246

Also, this is the second one I've had, dead pixel on the first, and they have both done this.

I did a test to see what keys it would type with notepad open and the on screen keyboard up as requested by someone in the comments and this is the result:

"     cc vv           nmm m m m m mcnvnv vnv v v v v v v v vnv v v v v v v v v v v v v vcvcvcvbv v v v v v v v v v vgv v vcvcvcvmv"

Comment: [su] might be a better place to ask, unless you're willing to write the disabler yourself

Comment: Weird, that screen is capacitive, so shouldn't register keys - does it register if you push something plastic against it?  Perhaps it is the screen pressing on the keyboard instead?  To find out which keys, change the power settings to "do nothing" when lid is closed, then open notepad and close the lid.  If any keys are typed, they'll appear in notepad.

Comment: @Paul Ya, I know it's supposed to be capacitive which is what is so odd... and no it doesn't do it if I press anything plastic up against it... could the keys be emitting too much power, lol? I've done three resets, for other reasons as well, which did not help. I finally did a fresh install wiping everything from the manufacturer, and all of my other problems are gone, which was dropbox constantly indexing and chrome not installing any new extensions saying that it couldn't unzip in some directory, which was valid. The keys it typed are up above

Comment: Those keys are all on the same row, and I am guessing there isn't a virtual keyboard onscreen when you close the lid (or when you open it)?  If not, I think it is likely the keyboard is bowed slightly and the keys are being pressed.

Comment: @Paul no I'm sure it's not the physical keys, as this is windows 8 so there is an onscreen keyboard that auto pops up when you fling the lockscreen up with a finger. Plus I can hear it making the typing sound which wouldn't happen if using the physical keyboard. Also, one time it got stuck or something and I could see the touch points, windows 8 auto shows touch points on the screen with visual feedback. So I could see ghost fingers on my screen slightly moving about awkwardly but staying in the same place. It wouldn't go away till I closed the screen again. Driver issue maybe?

Comment: Ah right. It is probably worth doing a diver upgrade, and opening a ticket at ASUS - it might be a damaged cable from the touchscreen, and activating a short or something when you close the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disable the touchscreen from device manager.
Windows Key-X and choose Device Manager.
Expand the Human Interface Devices.

Find the item associated with the touchscreen.  (I went down the list disabling until the touch stopped working.)

If, after finding the device, you want to script the disable/enable, you can use DevCon.exe.

Answer (score 0):

You know when you press Windows Key + P on your keyboard, there is an option called "second screen only". When I have second screen only. The builtin screen and touchscreen etc. are disabled.

When I unplug my USB dockingstation, the mainscreen comes on automatically. Thanks